# Remove question with sensitive info

Tags: discussion, support

I did a mistake by copying some code in some questions, then I edited the questions, and removed the screenshot.

The question is in sharepoint.stackexchange.com

However there is a website, which does not belong to stackexchange I suppose who pulls stackexchange information and questions

http://b.vniup.com/index.php/sharepoint/tricky-error-in-dialogbox-styling.html

Is there anyway you can help me to make that question be edited or removed from there?

Comment: Can't help you with an external site, but I can completely remove the revision that contains sensitive information if you give me a link to the question on Sharepoint SE and tell me which revision it is.

Answer (score 4):

I hate these sites that re-publish content and somehow get good search engine ranking - they clutter up search results without adding anything useful. However, our content is licenced under Creative Commons so they are entitled to do this, and there's not much we can do about it.

You could contact the site directly and ask them to remove or update the content. Most of these sites are spammy by nature so good luck with this.

I would guess that these sites are automated and that they will re-crawl our content periodically, so if you are patient the content might well get updated by itself.